# How to merge puppet array variables

Tags: puppet

Given the following puppet manifest, how can I merge / concatenate the two arrays such that the command will execute with both `a=b` and `b=c` ?

```
Cron{
  environment => ["a=b"]
}

class a{
  cron{'test':
    command     => "/usr/bin/true",
    user        => "francois",
    environment => ["b=c"],
  }
}

include a
```

My crontab entry ends up like this:

```
# Puppet Name: test
b=c
* * * * * /usr/bin/true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recall you can't do it directly.  Something like this might work though:

```
$default_env = ["a=b"]

Cron {
  environment => $default_env
}

class a {
  $additional_env = split(inline_template("<%= (default_env).join(',') %>"),',')

  cron {"test":
    command => "true",
    user => "me",
    environment => $additional_env
  }
}

include a
```

(the split/inline_template is based off of something from http://www.crobak.org/2011/02/two-puppet-tricks-combining-arrays-and-local-tests/ )

Comment: In this case, you don't need to go through all those machinations -- most Puppet providers/types will collapse nested arrays by themselves if nested arrays don't make sense in context. All you should need is something like: `$additional_env = [$default_env, 'b=c']`.

Comment: @jgoldschrafe Doesn't seem to be working on puppet 3.1 using cron itself.

Comment: If this is causing issues, the Puppet Labs stdlib does contain a flatten() function that's probably the simplest way to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

As of https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_data_array.html,

> ## Array operators
>
> You can use operators with arrays to create new
> arrays:
>
> - append with <<
> - **concatenate with +** [...]

you should be able to create a combined array like so

```
    environment => ["b=c"] + ["a=b"],
```

but you might want to [`join` the variables](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html) in another way.