# How to use puppets stored config & concat to generate a semicolon seperated list of ip adresses?

Tags: puppet

puppet version 2.7.18
stored configs (not puppetdb)

I my case i have 3 couchbase nodes, which should be concated to an couchbase connection string which looks like that:

```
192.168.19.12;192.168.19.40;192.168.19.66
```

so on each couchbase server i do something like this:

```
@@concat::fragment { "foo": target => '/tmp/foo', content => "$ipaddress", order => 1, }
```

and on the app server, which should connect to the couchbase server, i want generate a yaml config file looking like this:

```
  couchbase:
    class:          MyCouchbaseStorage
    param:
      connection:   MyCouchbaseConnection
      connection_param:
        username:     myusername
        password:     mypassword
        bucket:       mybucket
        host:         192.168.19.12;192.168.19.40;192.168.19.66
        persist:      1
```

all except the host lines are no problem, but the host entry is really tricky

i concat the hosts by collecting them with:

```
Concat::Fragment <<| tag == 'mycbtag' |>> { target => '/tmp/database.yml' }
```

so now i have the problem, that i have no ";"
calling concat like this

```
@@concat::fragment { "foo": target => '/tmp/foo', content => ";$ipaddress", order => 1, }
```

will produce:

```
host:         ;192.168.19.12;192.168.19.40;192.168.19.66
```

calling concat like that

```
@@concat::fragment { "foo": target => '/tmp/foo', content => "$ipaddress;", order => 1, }
```

will produce:

```
host:         192.168.19.12;192.168.19.40;192.168.19.66;
```

so how to modify the collected content or how do i get the desired result?

```
host:         192.168.19.12;192.168.19.40;192.168.19.66
```

Comment: Just a though, but why not use an `inline_template()` with the ruby `join()` function like in http://serverfault.com/a/350418/984

Comment: inline templates with resource collector? how should this work?

Comment: Why is `@@concat::fragment { "foo": target => '/tmp/foo', content => "$ipaddress", order => 1, }` not giving you the desired result? - As an aside, it is advisable to prefer functions from the `stdlib` module over `inline_template` for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this for Zookeeper using PuppetDB to retrieve the nodes, and a custom plugin to join them. The details of using PuppetDB are in the answer to my [original question](https://serverfault.com/a/646083/230046), and the custom plugin looks like this:

```
require 'puppet/face'
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
    newfunction(:comma_join_nodes, :type => :rvalue) do |args|
        query = args[0]
        fact = args[1]
        q = Puppet::Face[:query, :current].facts(query)
        return q.each_value.collect { |facts| facts[fact] }.sort.join(',')
    end
end
```

This should allow you to create a string in your manifest like this:

```
$nodes = comma_join_nodes('Class[couchbase]', ipaddress)
```

Which will use PuppetDB to find all nodes assigned the `couchbase` class, and return their IP addresses.

Note that this shoots for **eventual consistency** - it will take a run for all the nodes to report to PuppetDB that they have the `couchbase` class assigned, and only on the second run will they all connect. This works fine for my Zookeeper class, but I suppose may not quite suit for the Couchbase one.

Comment: looks like a good solution, but in my case it is a legacy system which is using puppet 2.7 with stored configs.