# how to make our servers aware of the names of the other servers in the environment in Puppet

Tags: puppet, hiera

Can you please guide me on how I can use hiera or site.pp to make our servers aware of the names of the other servers in the environment?
for example ,
we have 10 servers in uat2 ,Id like to get a list of them into puppet such that the servers know what others are available

Comment: puppetdb and exported resources

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [PuppetDB](https://docs.puppet.com/puppetdb/5.1/), which is designed for exactly this. In particular it allows the use of Exported Resources, so that all hosts in a group can export a resource and it can be collected on another node.

I had a similar issue a while ago, the solution to which is [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/646061/deploying-distributed-apps-with-puppet-advice/646083#646083). The combination of PuppetDB and the [Hiera backend](https://github.com/dalen/puppet-puppetdbquery) for it should do what you wish.